# Replacing characters with some restrictions

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a list of strings in Python and I want to create a function that perform many replacements. Some of them are:

- Replace "o agrícola" for "trabajo agrícola"
- Replace "ob agricola" for "trabajo agrícola"

One solution that comes to my mind is:

```
text = str(text).replace('o agricola','trabajo agrícola')
text = str(text).replace('t agricola','trabajo agrícola')
```

One of the issues:

```
text = 'obrero agricola' is transformed into 'obrertrabajo agrícola'
```

Is there a solution that **respects these two conditions**?

- 'obrero agricola' is mapped into 'obrero agrícola'
- 'o something' is mapped into 'o something' (it fixes 'o' if it's mixed with other words)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use word boundaries along with `re.sub`:

```py
text = 'ob agricola and obrero agricola'
text = re.sub(r'\b(?:o agrícola|ob agricola)', 'trabajo agrícola', text)
print(text)  # trabajo agrícola and obrero agricola
```